# Give json data in php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I want insert in two-column database data `woid` and `json_data`, i can not getting value `json_data` for inset in database, How is it?

```
$data_end = json_decode('[
  {
    "woid": "2254271",
    "json_data": [
      {
        "code": "23",
        "date": "Tue, 03 Jan 2017 03:30 PM IRST",
        "temp": "68",
        "text": "Breezy"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "woid": "2254271",
    "json_data": [
      {
        "code": "23",
        "date": "Tue, 03 Jan 2017 03:30 PM IRST",
        "temp": "68",
        "text": "Breezy"
      }
    ]
  }
]');

foreach($data_end as $idx=>$val){
  $this->admin_model->UpdateData('weather', array('json_data' => $val->json_data), array('woid' => $val->woid));
}
```

And give me this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Notice
>  Message: Array to
>   string conversion
>  Filename: database/DB_driver.php
>  Line
>   Number: 1524
>  
>  Error Number: 1054
>  Unknown column
>   'Array' in 'field list'
>  UPDATE `weather` SET `json_data` = Array
>   WHERE `woid` = '2254271'
>  Filename: models/model.php
>  Line
>   Number: 39

Comment: `$val->json_data` will give you array not string, so you can't insert

Comment: What do i do???

Comment: actually it depended on what you actually want to insert from `json_data`? Or you want to insert json encoded data ?

Comment: ok, i use of `json_encode`. it worked.

Comment: good that you get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse an array in the query.

You could json_encode the array before inserting it.

```
$this->admin_model->UpdateData('weather', array('json_data' => json_encode($val->json_data)), array('woid' => $val->woid));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$val->json_data` is an array, you have to change it to string with `json_encode( $val->json_data)` before you insert to your db.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because you are trying to use PHP Array() in MySQl Query and it will not allowed you need to use `json_encode()` methos to save data.

you can update like that --

```
$json_data = json_encode($val->json_data);

$this->admin_model->UpdateData('weather', array('json_data' => $json_data), array('woid' => $val->woid));
```